# How would I securely pass a salt to the web crypto API?

Tags: javascript, security, next.js, cryptography

I am using the web crypto API to compute a hash:

```js
  const encoder = new TextEncoder();
  const salt = "foo"; 
  const data = encoder.encode(str + salt); 
  const hash = await crypto.subtle.digest("SHA-256", data);
```

What I don't understand is, how would I possibly pass a salt to this in a secure way, without someone being able to read it?

Context: next.js doesn't let you use crypto node module in middleware. I need to use the crypto module for auth, so they suggest using the web crypto API [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/node-module-in-edge-runtime).

Comment: Short answer, you don't. A salt should not be kept secret, a key should, so hypothetically you're making the salt behave like a key. Think about it this way, even if the attacker has the salt, what is the risk? He/she/they has/have the hash and the salt, and then what...?